# Why PHP memory_limit instruction in php ini is ignored?

Tags: php, apache

I have set the memory_limit in my php.ini like this:

```
root@web:/var/www/html# grep -r memory_limit /usr/local/etc/php
/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production:memory_limit = 5G
/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development:memory_limit = 5G
```

(btw, I don't know why I have two php.ini files)

Anyway, I restart apache, and I see that these instructions are not used:

```
root@web:/var/www/html# service apache2 restart
 * Restarting Apache httpd web server apache2                                                                                                       

root@web:/var/www/html# php -i | grep memory
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
```

As far as I checked, the php ini files are the ones that are actually used:

```
root@web:/var/www/html# php -i | grep ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
```

Any idea what is the issue?

Comment: There's a CLI and a webserver-version of PHP. Since you use the CLI, it only shows values for your CLI php. Use `phpinfo()` in a file _on your webserver_ to get the location of the webserver php.ini

Comment: Also, I think `php.ini-production` and `php.ini-development`  are just "templates" for a certain environment, you'd need to rename one of them (probably php.ini-development for you dev environment) to `php.ini` to make it work

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That was the issue. I did `cp php.ini-production php.ini` and it solved it. Thanks a lot. Put it as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a `php.ini` in that folder for it to work. `php.ini-production` and `php.ini-development` are just "templates" with different settings. You need to rename/copy one of those:

`cp php.ini-production php.ini`